# Как получить текст с raw сайта pastebin

Tags: c#

Есть вот такой сайт при открытии там ничего нету кроме текста: https://pastebin.com/raw/CasNh6yd
Как мне получить данный текст на c#

Comment: `await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(@"https://pastebin.com/raw/CasNh6yd")`

Comment: Ошибка CS4033 Оператор await можно использовать только в методах с модификатором async. Попробуйте пометить этот метод модификатором async и изменить тип его возвращаемого значения на Task.

Comment: Ага, все верно написано что надо сделать

Comment: всё решил спасибо ;)

Comment: Напишите ответ со своим решением

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей._ - вставьте нерабочий код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Обязательно прочитайте [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) и [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: я воспользовался встроенной функцией visualstudio

Comment: как пометить ответ ?

Comment: @ДенисВолков - чтобы пометить ответ, его нужно сначала добавить именно как "ответ". Если Вам интересно и есть 5 мин - можете сами написать ответ, просто скопоновав его из комментариев, и сами его пометить. Я не думаю, что кто то будет против, так как полный ответ никто не написал. Вам это принесет баллы репутации.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:
`await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(@"https://pastebin.com/raw/CasNh6yd")`

Comment: Обратите внимание на [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1): _`HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use._